# Arte there any free alternatives to packages "translate" and "translateR"?

Tags: r, translation

Both have been removed from CRAN and I can't get the archived versions because of a problem with devtools.

Comment: You don't have to use devtools to install archived packages. You can download them straight from CRAN and use `install.packages()` pointing directly at the downloaded files.

Comment: In case it's just `devtools` that's a problem, you might be able to use `remotes::install_github("cran/translate")`. However ... both `translate` and `translateR` are over 8 years old, and while I don't know the differences, it seems likely that the APIs they are meant to support have changed (or at least are recommending newer endpoints).